# How to create NSIS installer QGIS with Microsoft Visual C++?

Tags: qgis, installation, visual-studio, windows-7, visual-c++

I want to know, there is a way to generate QGIS NSIS installer with a Release build generated with Microsoft Visual C++?
It is possible to generate the installer in Windows Operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QGIS installer code is available for inspection at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/ms-windows

Instructions for building and packaging (with Visual Studio) are provided in the install guide, section 4: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL#L541